# Allow non-admin user to shutdown/reboot Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, user-permissions

Anyone know if a setting exists to allow a non-admin user to shutdown a server?

Obviously I can set the "Allow Server to shutdown without logon" GPO but that is not quite the same thing.  I am looking for a way to properly assign the shutdown right to a particular user if possible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can assign this in either a GPO or Local Security Policy.

The setting that you're looking for is in `Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Shutdown the system`

[image]

Comment: Thanks MDMarra, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Even allows for individual users or groups to be added to the list.  In my case I added the "Hyper-V Administrators" group to the shutdown list.

Comment: Does it only work with shutting down or also with restart?

Answer (score 0):

use "force shutdown from a remote system" then you can build a script like
`shutdown -r -t 120 -m "hostname"` to restart the system remotely.

- `-r` = restart
- `-t` = time in seconds
- `-m` = Target here you have to enter IP or hostname